# After removing dhcp networking is not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

After uninstalling dhcp in ubuntu. Entire networking itself is not working

ifconfig is empty
but ifconfig -a is listing all interfaces
Unable to connect with anynetwork
Tried:
Reboot
Restarting networking services
ifup and ifdown also not working

Comment: Unclear why you're surprised, or why you did this strange thing. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall the DHCP utility for a reason?  Nearly 100% of home and wifi networks depend on DHCP (the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) to function properly and automatically?  DHCP is responsible for telling the network that your device has connected to the network, requesting an IP address, and other critical pieces of network information.  Without DHCP you will have to statically/manually assign these pieces of information:

1. IP Address (e.g. 192.168.1.101)
2. Netmask (most homes uses 255.255.255.0)
3. Gateway/Router (e.g. 192.168.1.1)
4. DNS Server (sometimes it's the same as the gateway/router)